# whitelist discord py игнорит сообщения

Tags: python, discord

```py
    whitelist = ['Тест', 'тест']
        if message.channel == channel and not message.author.bot and message.content in whitelist:
```

Доброго времени суток!
Пишу бота для дискорда, у меня есть вайтлист сообщений который бот не должен игнорировать, но когда я что либо добавляю к тексту.
Пример тест 123123, бот игнорирует данное сообщение

Comment: Написать правильно условие, почитать как работают логические операторы

Comment: напиши правильное условие пожалуйста.

Comment: `not message.author.bot` Что в вашем понимании это должно делать?

Comment: игнорирует сообщения от ботов

Comment: Обновите вопрос и напишите, что в каждом объекте содержится и что вы ожидаете увидеть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты делаешь неправильную проверку нахождения слов из вайтлиста в тексте.

```
whitelist = ['Тест', 'тест']

if message.author.bot:
    return

if not message.channel == channel:
    return

for word in whitelist:
    if word in message.content:
        break
else:
    return
```

В таком случае мы проходимся по всем словам из вайтлиста и проверяем содержится ли оно в сообщение. Если мы не вышли из цикла брейком, то сработает **else** и мы выйдем из функции. Могу еще предположить, что стоит добавить

```
message.content.lower()
```

Дабы не писать одни и те же слова в разных регистрах, а написать один раз в  нижнем.